# Eager loading last subordinate record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Suppose that model X has_many Ys and model Y belongs_to X. Each Y has a date when it has been inserted to the database. Now, is it possible to load all Xs and eager load last Y for each of X (only the last because each X has bazzilions of Ys)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes,

Lets take this example

```
class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :votes
end

class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :song
end
```

Add a new association to the Song

```
# for Rails version <4:
has_one :last_vote, :class_name => 'Vote', :order => 'created_at DESC'

# for Rails version 4+
has_one :last_vote, -> { order(created_at: :desc) }, class_name: 'Vote'
```

this new association will always return the most recently created Vote for a Song.

To eager load it

```
# for Rails version <3:
songs = Song.find(:all, :conditions => 'artist_name = "frank"', :include => :last_vote)

# for Rails version 3+:
songs = Song.includes(:last_vote).where(artist_name: 'frank')
```

Comment: It would be interesting to see the join generated by that query. :)  It'll probably be best to denormalize a bit and add a field to Song, last_vote_id, updated everytime a new vote is added.  Just :include => :last_vote afterwards, no superfluous data loads (or GROUP BY, if smart) needed.

Comment: True, my above code is totally untested.  Vlad, your solution sounds like an improvement over mine.

Comment: This will still preload all votes for each Song, not only the first one. This will generate query as like
SELECT “votes”.* FROM “votes” WHERE “votes”.”song_id” IN (1,2,3,4,5) order by created_at DESC

Answer (score 0):

The previous solution is really great! However, I'm looking for one more feature: is it possible to eager load last subordinate record before a specific date? This is needed so that my users can browse a history a song's votes (with links to previous and next days).